# Javascript turn off multiple devices but exclude the ones in array

Tags: javascript

Rebuilt my code. I can turn off only the devices in the array but I would like to do the opposite, turn off all but the ones in the array.
How to swap that? I am using != (Not equal to) but it doesn't care about that.

```
let devices = await Homey.devices.getDevices();

var DeviceNames = [
"Kitchentable - Right", 
"Kitchentable - Middle", 
"Kitchentable - Left"
];

DeviceNames.forEach(function(element) {
  _.forEach(devices, device => {
    if(device.class != 'light') return;
    if(!device.state.onoff) return;
    if(device.name != element) return;
    device.setCapabilityValue('onoff', false);
    console.log(device.name);
  }
});

return true;
```

CONSOLE OUTPUT

```
Kitchentable - Right
Kitchentable - Middle
Kitchentable - Left

----------------
Script returned:
 true
```

Comment: No one with some javascript skills who could give me some hints?

Comment: Can you give us dummy input and expected output?

Comment: Ofcourse, added above

Comment: Why do you use both the native `Array.forEach` and lodash’s `_.forEach`?

Comment: This is what I managed to put together to loop through both alll devices from Homey and loopthrough the array. Can I combine them somehow?